# GameObject not destroyed in ExecuteInEditMode and spooky Instantiating

Tags: unity, c#

I was trying to get familiar with Unity's *ExecuteInEditMode*

Everything is fine it keeps the old object although I have deleted them.

And one more thing, although every-thing (cube) is instantiated is set as child of GameObject script is attached to, they where the other cubes come from?

I have this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Road : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    private int count = 0;
    void Start()
    {}
    void Update()
    {
        if(count!=points.Count)
        {
            count = points.Count;
            foreach(GameObject g in gameObjects)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(g);
            }
            gameObjects.Clear();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Vector3 point in points)
            {
                Debug.Log(++i + "  " + point);
                GameObject tem = Instantiate(GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube), point, Quaternion.identity);
                tem.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                gameObjects.Add(tem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a snap:

[image]

Comment: Can you walk us through the sequence of events that leads to these cubes appearing in your scene, starting from a completely empty scene? In particular, call out any steps that cause a serialization/deserialization pass, like saving/opening the scene or entering/exiting play mode.

Comment: It was Unity's SampleScene with camera and Light, then I created an empty GameObject then created the script. After that, set value to *2,3,1*

Comment: And there is exactly *2+3+1=6* cubes  and created sequentially, why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake :

```
            GameObject tem = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            tem.transform.position = point;
```

added replacing

```
GameObject tem = Instantiate(GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube), point, Quaternion.identity);
```

2 Cubes were created on that line every time.